# dot 2 pixels together

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86, dos, framebuffer

I dot a pixel right next first pixel but the result is different. Second pixel is far away from first one.

What's wrong?

```
org 100h
;change to 320x200 graphic mode
mov ax, 13
int 10h

;frame buffer location
push 0xa000
pop es
xor di, di

;dot 2 pixels
mov ax, 1
mov [es:di], ax
inc di
mov [es:di], ax

;prevent ending
a:
jmp a
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two bugs.

First, BIOS 320x200 at 8 bits/pixel is video mode `13h` (`19d`), not `13d` as you have.

To fix it:

```
mov ax,13h
int 10h
```

The other bug is that you write `ax` instead of `al` to video memory. Replace `ax` with `al` or any other 8-bit register (`ah`, `bl`, `bh`, `cl`, `ch`, `dl`, `dh`):

```
mov al,1
mov [es:di],al
inc di
mov [es:di],al
```

That should do it.